# How to send files via HTTP_POST with Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, http-post, winhttprequest

The question asked here: [How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba) is almost exactly what I was looking for except that I am trying to send a number of files to the server. I googled further and found [How do I upload a zip file via HTTP post using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939578/how-do-i-upload-a-zip-file-via-http-post-using-vba) This was also good, but pretty discouraging - it seems like a lot of work (not just making an HTML form here...).

Option #2 here: http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_post-binary-data-url/ (as cited in the question on SO noted above) seems like it would work well, but as I work in JS and CSS, I have no idea how to create FormData (the binary files to send to the server) in the example.

Can anyone please help me? In essence, I want to send 3-6 files over HTTP_POST via VBA from inside Excel to a PHP script on a web server that is expecting form data such as . An HTML form to handle this would look like:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT -- Aug. 2nd 2012

I'm still trying to work on this issue. I don't know VBA/6, pretty much just basic JS so I am a little lost. Here is what I have done so far:

```
Sub HTTPInternetPutFile()

    ' create new object with WinHttpRequest for this operation
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Dim FormFields As String

    ' initialize variables that we will set and pass as parameters
    Dim sfpath
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim StrFileName As String


       StrFileName = "CLIPrDL.csv"
       sfpath = "C:\CLIPr\"
       strURL = "http://s0106001c10187ab1.gv.shawcable.net/uploadtest/upload_file.php"


       WinHttpReq.Open "POST", strURL, False


       ' Set headers
       WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
       WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8"
       WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
       ' WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF8"
       WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=""userfile[]"""

       ' I dont understand this... why use fileup??
       FormFields = """filename=" & StrFileName & """"
       FormFields = FormFields & "&"
       FormFields = FormFields & sfpath

       ' so comment it out for now
       ' WinHttpReq.Send FormFields
       WinHttpReq.Send sfpath & StrFileName

       ' output this var to a message box becuase I dont know what it does really
       MsgBox FormFields
       ' Display the status code and response headers.
       MsgBox WinHttpReq.GetAllResponseHeaders
       MsgBox WinHttpReq.ResponseText


End Sub
```

The message boxes at the bottom of the script do output the server's headers and response (blank HTML page). I feel that there is something that I am not setting in the headers to make the server happy (note: trying commenting out Content-Type).

If anyone out there has experience using the WinHttpRequest object in VBA/6 to POST a binary file via HTTP, please help! :)

Comment: What kind of files: text or binary?

Comment: Would you be able to send the files one by one?  Or is that not an option?

Comment: @TimWilliams binary, excel files.

Comment: @ikh Yes! I think that I could do that. But still, as I know only JS I don't know how to do that, or if it can be done. I get that I can send params but binary data????

Comment: This is VB6 but should also work in VBA/Excel:  http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/

Comment: @TimWilliams I'll give it a whirl on Monday! Thank you!

Comment: I've finally got this working! It was a pain for sure! Used Wireshark to see the server's headers and then matched those in code. Finally working. @TimWilliams, your link was very helpful - thank you. Put it as an answer if you like, and I will mark it/up vote it. Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This (using WinInet) is VB6 but should also work in VBA/Excel:

http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/

Comment: If you are using a 64 bit version of Excel then you will need to add PtrSafe to your declared functions. Example: Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetAutodial

Comment: I can't get this code to work... What library references do I need to make?

Answer (score 3):

I'm successfully using the one below (it uses ADODB.Stream and WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1):

http://www.ericphelps.com/scripting/samples/reference/web/http_post.txt

<sup>(if website disappears, also [available on Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20160423151412/http://www.ericphelps.com/scripting/samples/reference/web/http_post.txt))</sup>

Comment: But with no explanation how it is deployed? An example would have made this so much more useful.