# VBA Outlook attachments post to URL

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have created a macro for outlook which opens up a userform, asks a few questions to select from, and then there's a submit button to send the message and the userform data to a POST url (our ticketing system).  I am stuck on the last part of attachments. I can see the attachments list and loop through the attachment item objects, but I don't know which object call to make to send the actual file data to the POST form... all i can see is file size, file name, etc.

Any ideas where i would get the file contents and mime type for adding them to the URL post action as a form var?

```
Public senderaddress As String
Public thisEmailContent As String
Public thisEmailTEXT As String
Public thisStaffMember As Integer
Public emailAttachments As String

Sub MacroName()
    thisStaffMember = 1
    Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
    senderaddress = objItem.SenderEmailAddress
    thisEmailContent = objItem.HTMLBody
    thisEmailTEXT = objItem.Body
    emailAttachments = objItem.Attachments
    UserformName.Show
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
        Set GetCurrentItem = _
        objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
        Set GetCurrentItem = _
        objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Case Else
    End Select
End Function
```

Then here's the last part of the Userform code where it actually sends the data to our ticket system when the **Send Now** button is clicked...

```
Public Function encodeURL(str As String)
    Dim ScriptEngine As Object
    Dim encoded As String

    Set ScriptEngine = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")
    ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    encoded = ScriptEngine.Run("encodeURIComponent", str)

    encodeURL = encoded
End Function

Private Sub SendNow_Click()
    Set sendReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With sendReq
        .Open "POST", "https://ticketsystemurl.whatever/outlookinterface.php?action=openticket&fromEmail=" & encodeURL(senderaddress) & "&selectedCustomer=" & encodeURL(CustomerSelect.Value) & "&selectedContact=" & encodeURL(ContactSelect.Value), False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send ("notifyCustomer=" & NotifyCustomer.Value & "&staffID=" & thisStaffMember & "&emailContent=" & encodeURL(thisEmailContent) & "&emailTEXT=" & encodeURL(thisEmailTEXT) & "&appendTicket=" & AppendToTicket.Value & "&createNewTicket=" & CreateNewTicket.Value & "&selectedTicket=" & encodeURL(SelectTicket.Value) & "&attachments=" & encodeURL(emailAttachments))
    End With

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

so far that submits everything except i cant figure out how to populate the post var "attachments" with the actual attachment filedata.  Is this even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954293/how-to-send-files-via-http-post-with-excel-using-vba

Comment: that's Excel, excel doesnt have attachments

Comment: Save the attachments to disk and it's the same after that step.  https://www.slipstick.com/developer/save-attachments-to-the-hard-drive/

Answer (score 0):

Outlook would not do that for you. You will need to save the attachment as a file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`), the read the contents of that file ([Scripting.FileSystemObject](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/186118/how-to-use-filesystemobject-with-visual-basic) object?) to use it in your web request.